# Oracle Apex - editing detail form in Master Detail form

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, master-detail

I've created a master detail form using the wizard.  I can get LOV selects to work in the edit master table part of the form, but I want my detail forms to also have a LOV dropdown.

I just can't find where to add this - I can't find the detail fields anywhere on the edit page area for the master detail page I've created.

How can I do this??  I hope this is easy to answer - I feel as though I must be missing something obvious.

Comment: I've found that if I ask the wizard to "Edit detail on a separate page." then I can get that page to have a LOV, but I'd still like to be able to do it when they're on the one page.

Comment: You are talking tabular forms then? Which apex version? (since i can choose popup lov for a column in apex 4.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question - it's there, but it's quite well hidden!

You find and select the details form in the Regions section of the main form page.  Then choose the Report Attributes tab.  Click on the yellow pencil next to the field you want to edit and add your LOV.

That seems obvious now, but took me over an hour of fiddling to find!